# ASP.NETCore Yoeman and Dotnet CLI examples are failing out of the box for me, why>

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I'm a newbie at trying to use my JavaScript skills with ASP.NET Core.

Using Yoeman, I get an error after these steps:

```
    npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa
    npm install -g webpack
    yo aspnetcore-spa
```

The error is:

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'temp'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bruce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\external-editor\main\index.js:15:10)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bruce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\external-editor\main\index.js:136:4)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

What should I do to fix this?
```

Also after this error, to try something else I went to the Dotnet CLI and tried this:

```
    dotnet new reactredux
    dotnet restore
    yarn install
    dotnet run
```

The error is:

```
    Hosting environment: Development
    Content root path: C:\Users\Bruce\Dropbox\Projects MoneyPlan\MyNewThing
    Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
    Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
          (node:10072) DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]

          parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
          [at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
          [at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
          webpack built f9fa10795e41d7865b35 in 12041ms
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
          Hash: f9fa10795e41d7865b35
          Version: webpack 2.5.1
          Time: 12041ms
                       Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
              main-client.js    299 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main-client
                    site.css   1.56 kB       0  [emitted]         main-client
          main-client.js.map    333 kB       0  [emitted]         main-client
                site.css.map  85 bytes       0  [emitted]         main-client
          chunk    {0} main-client.js, site.css, main-client.js.map, site.css.map (main-client) 244 kB [entry] [rendered]
              [0] external "vendor_609a3b1255e87fe0584f" 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable]
              [1] delegated ./node_modules/react/react.js from dll-reference vendor_609a3b1255e87fe0584f 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable] [built]
             [59] ./ClientApp/boot-client.tsx 938 bytes {0} [built]
             [60] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?path=%2F__webpack_hmr 6.68 kB {0} [built]
             [61] delegated ./node_modules/event-source-polyfill/eventsource.js from dll-reference vendor_609a3b1255e87fe0584f 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable] [built]
             [69] ./ClientApp/configureStore.ts 1.35 kB {0} [built]
             [70] ./ClientApp/routes.tsx 743 bytes {0} [built]
             [71] ./ClientApp/css/site.css 41 bytes {0} [built]
            [177] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
            [178] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client-overlay.js 1.82 kB {0} [built]
            [179] (webpack)-hot-middleware/process-update.js 3.88 kB {0} [built]
            [180] delegated ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js from dll-reference vendor_609a3b1255e87fe0584f 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable] [built]
            [182] delegated ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js from dll-reference vendor_609a3b1255e87fe0584f 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable] [built]
            [186] delegated ./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js from dll-reference vendor_609a3b1255e87fe0584f 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable] [built]
            [189] multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=%2F__webpack_hmr ./ClientApp/boot-client.tsx 52 bytes {0} [built]
               + 175 hidden modules

          ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Layout.tsx:13:21
              TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<NavMenu> & { children?: ReactNode; } & void'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'void'.
          Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
              chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 3.32 kB [entry] [rendered]
                  [0] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
                  [1] ./~/css-loader!./ClientApp/css/site.css 1.81 kB {0} [built]
```

If I point my browser at http://localhost:5000/ anyway to see what happens, I get this error:

```
    ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Layout.tsx:13:21 
        TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<NavMenu> & { children?: ReactNode; } & void'.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

I'm at a loss here, with all these examples failing out of the box. Any help?

Comment: I had a smilar issue. Try updating your typescript version and node version.

Comment: I tried it again, after running npm install -g typescript@latest. Got some different errors this time doing the dotnet CLI sequence. Then I opened VS Code in the project, and from within the VS Code's command window I ran dotnet run. The project worked this time when I pointed my browser to http://localhost:5000. I shut down and went back the external command window and ran dotnet run there. Now pointing my browser to http://localhost:5000 worked here too this time. I think VS Code does some under-the-covers clean up to the bootstrap CLI framework.

Comment: I want to take my working react app, and put the components into the reactredux app. But i get an error saying that '--allowJs' is not set. Seems like it is a recognized problem, but without a solution so far. 

I thought I did all the required steps. I modified the tsconfig.json file to include "allowJs":true. I added a simple Aboutjs test component, added a menu in the NavBar, fixed the routes.tsx file. But it fails when run with this:
Call to Node module failed ...... components\About.js Unexpected token (5:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

What now?